# How to pass "&" operator to next php page and get to display at page?

Tags: php

Hello Friends i have some little problem with my query and i m not able to solve it.

I M using to pass this

```
$comp = mysql_query("SELECT * from abc order by name ASC");
            $count = mysql_num_rows($comp);

            $data = array();

                while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($comp)) {
                  $l = urlencode($row['name'][0]); // first letter/number
                    $category_list[$l][]=( $row['name']);

                }?>
                <ul>
                <?php
                if(is_array($category_list)){
                foreach($category_list as $k=>$v ) {?>
                    <div class="comp_num"><h3><u><?php echo $k ?></u></h3></div> 
                    <div class="comp_list">
                <?php
                    foreach($v as $cat) {
                      //echo "<div>$cat</div>"; // category name?>
                      <li><a href="www.abc.com?.c=<?php echo $cat ?>"><?php echo $cat ?></a></li>
                  <?php }?>

                </div>
                 <?php }?>
                  </ul>
                <?php
                }
                ?>
```

**www.abc.com/p_review_page?c=1%20C%20&%20C%20incorporation%20Ltd.**

when I execute this code then this code is escaping all string from "&" operator

```
<?php 
            if(isset($_GET["c"]))
            {
            $c=mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['c']);
            }   
            echo "$c";      
            }
?>
```

I m getting this result : **1 C**

But i want to display "**1 C & C incorporation Ltd.**"

how to solve it.. please help

Comment: `echo htmlspecialchars($c);` to output into html and `urlencode($c)` to output to URL

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php

Comment: How did you manage to encode the spaces, but not the ampersand? And what's the purpose of `mysql_real_escape_string` prior outputting the string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$url = '?' . http_build_query(array(
  'say' => 'A & B'
));
```

// Then just:

```
echo $_GET['say'];
```

**UPDATE**

```
$category_list=http_build_query(array(1=>'C & C in',2=>'A & B'));
```

or you can put your array like

```
is_array(http_build_query($category_list))
```

Comment: Ravi sir i have updated my question will you please give exam by my coding please

Comment: get me the output format of category list , i ll try to do, if possible @Anuveester

Answer (score 4):

`&` is the separator between parameters in a URL. If you want to include it literally in a parameter, it has to be encoded in hex as `%26`, so it should be:

```
www.abc.com/p_review_page?c=1%20C%20%26%20C%20incorporation%20Ltd.
```

If you're creating the URL in PHP, you should use `urlencode()` to encode each parameter. Here is the code:

```
foreach($v as $cat) { ?>
    <li><a href="www.abc.com?c=<?php echo urlencode($cat) ?>"><?php echo htmlentities($cat) ?></a></li>
<?php }?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You aren't properly encoding your URL in the first place.  Ampersand `&` becomes `%26`.  Otherwise, it is used as a delimiter for more query string variables.

Also, when you want to echo a variable, don't use string interpolation... just echo it:

```
echo $c;
```

And finally, you should consider switching to PDO and using prepared/parameterized queries.  The `mysql_*` set of functions will be removed from PHP soon.  At a minimum, there is MySQLi.